# Add code to UIScrollViewDelegate method

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want to add something to `scrollViewDidScroll`. You have two possibilities:

No.1

```
public override void Scrolled (UIScrollView scrollView){
    this.contentOffset = TableView.ContentOffset;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Scrolled is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override.
```

It's clear because I have to put this into my `UIScrollViewDelegate`. But I'm using the default one provided by Xamarin.

No. 2

```
TableView.Scrolled += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    this.contentOffset = TableView.ContentOffset;
};
```

If I do this all my default delegate methods are gone. `RowSelected` doesn't work anymore. I only want to add this line of code, but I don't want to write my own delegate methods.

How can I easily add one line of code to detect the end of scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `UITableViewSource` (which subclass `UIScrollViewDelegate`) then you can override both the `RowSelected` and `Scrolled` methods (on which the event is based on).